# Completions of $K(x)$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, fields, valuation-theory, non-archimedean-fields

Let $K$ be a field. Are there books or articles discussing completions of $K(x)$ with respect to the metric induced by the $p$-adic valuation $|\;\;|_p$ where $p\in k[x]$ is irreducible and **different from $x$**?

I am interested in the description of the coefficients of the $p$-adic expansion of a rational function in the completion of $(K(x),|\;\;|_p)$.

For example, in the case $p=x$, the coefficients of the $x$-adic expansion of a rational function in $K((x))$ is an eventually linearly recurrent sequence.
A sequence $(r_n)_n$ of elements of $K$ is  *linearly recurrent*
if there exist constants $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k\in K$ such that 
\begin{equation}\label{linear recurrence}
r_{n+k}=c_1r_{n}+c_2r_{n+1}+\cdots+c_kr_{n+k-1}
\end{equation}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
What about the case $p\neq x$?

Comment: Here is an example to think about: completing $\mathbf Q(x)$ at $|\cdot|_{x^2+1}$ will be $\mathbf Q(i)((\pi))$ where $\pi = x^2+1$. This is analogous to completing a number field at a prime ideal with residue field degree greater than $1$. Completing $K(x)$ at $x-c$ gives you $K((x-c))$, so not interesting for your purposes.